# CPlex coding logic

Tags: optimization, cplex, ampl

The professor in charge of an industrial engineering design course is faced with the problem of assigning 28 students to 8 projects. Each student must be assigned to one project and each project group must have 3 or 4 students. The students have been asked to rank the projects, with 1 being the best ranking and higher numbers representing lower rankings.

a)  Formulate an OPL model for this problem.

b)  Solve the assignment problem for the following table of assignments:

```
    A   ED  EZ  G   H1  H2  RB  SC
Allen   1   3   4   7   7   5   2   6
Black   6   4   2   5   5   7   1   3
Chung   6   2   3   1   1   7   5   4
Clark   7   6   1   2   2   3   5   4
Conners 7   6   1   3   3   4   5   2
Cumming 6   7   4   2   2   3   5   1
Demming 2   5   4   6   6   1   3   7
Eng     4   7   2   1   1   6   3   5
Farmer  7   6   5   2   2   1   3   4
Forest  6   7   2   5   5   1   3   4
Goodman 7   6   2   4   4   5   1   3
Harris  4   7   5   3   3   1   2   6
Holmes  6   7   4   2   2   3   5   1
Johnson 2   2   4   6   6   5   3   1
Knorr   7   4   1   2   2   5   6   3
Manheim 4   7   2   1   1   3   6   5
Morris  7   5   4   6   6   3   1   2
Nathan  4   7   5   6   6   3   1   2
Neuman  7   5   4   6   6   3   1   2
Patrick 1   7   5   4   4   2   3   6
Rollins 6   2   3   1   1   7   5   4
Schuman 4   7   3   5   5   1   2   6
Silver  4   7   3   1   1   2   5   6
Stein   6   4   2   5   5   7   1   3
Stock   5   2   1   6   6   7   4   3
Truman  6   3   2   7   7   5   1   4
Wolman  6   7   4   2   2   3   5   1
Young   1   3   4   7   7   6   2   5
```

How many students are assigned their second or third choice?

c)  Some of the projects are harder than others to reach without a car. Thus, it is desirable that at least a certain number of students assigned to each project must have a car; the numbers vary by project as follows:

```
A   ED  EZ  G   H1  H2  RB  SC
1   0   0   2   2   2   1   1
```

The students who have cars are Chung, Demming, Eng, Holmes, Manheim, Morris, Nathan, Patrick, Rollins and Young.

Modify the model to add this car constraint and solve the problem again. How many more students than before must be assigned second or third choices?

I coded the file for a) & b) but i am getting stuck at c).
can anyone help pls with the logic? even ampl wil suffice

Answer (score 0):

Let `C_i` be the indicator matrix (input): `C_i = 1` if student `i` has a car and 0 otherwise. I'll assume you have the following decision variables:

```
x_ij = 1 if student i is assigned to project j; 0 otherwise
```

then c) constraint can me modeled as follows

```
sum_i C_i * x_ij >= b_j    for all j
```

where `b_j` is

```
 j   A   ED  EZ  G   H1  H2  RB  SC
 b_j 1   0   0   2   2   2   1   1
```

Comment: can u suggest a manual/book from where i can learn to code cplex?